# Custom View Controller Transition clips views to bounds

Tags: objective-c, iphone, animation, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have two view controllers with a custom flip animation as the transition. This is the guide I followed for the transitions: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html. This works fine, except the view clipped to the bounds that constrain the view while stationary. During the animation, the view exceeds these bounds to simulate some perspective.

What I have found is that there is a `UINavigationTransitionView` added to the subview tree during the animation. This has clipsToBounds set to YES, which I don't want.

I can intercept this view and change clipsToBounds to NO by placing this at the top of the navigation controller delegate method `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:`

```
UIView *firstSubview = [view.subviews firstObject];
firstSubview.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

But this is very hacky at best. Is there a setting to disable clipsToBounds during the view controller transition?

Comment: I am actually facing the same issue right now. Did you ever come up with a better solution than modifying the properties through the delegate?

Comment: Any solution on that yet?